# Using colum names in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below code which searches for specific text based on the Col header, like Col O, Col P etc. Instead I want to search using the respective column name in Row 1.

I have added the column name in  the code comments.

```
Sub PassFailValidationandupdatecomments()

Dim Rng As Range, cl As Range
Dim LastRow As Long, MatchRow As Variant

With Sheets("DRG")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.count, "E").End(xlUp).Row '"E" - Live ASIN
    Set Rng = .Range("E2:E" & LastRow) ' "E" - Live ASIN
End With

With Sheets("Latency")
    For Each cl In .Range("B2:B" & .Cells(.Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row) ` "B" - ASIN
        MatchRow = Application.Match(cl.Value, Rng, 0) 
        If Not IsError(MatchRow) Then 

            Select Case Sheets("DRG").Range("AH" & MatchRow + 1).Value ' "AH" - Final Test Result

                    .Range("O" & cl.Row).Value = "Pass" '"O" - Pass/Fail

                    Case "Pended"
                    .Range("O" & cl.Row).Value = "Fail"'"O" - Pass/Fail

                Case "In progress"
                    .Range("O" & cl.Row).Value = "In progress"'"O" - Pass/Fail                End Select

                  If Not Sheets("DRG").Range("E" & MatchRow + 1).Value = vbNullString Then .Range("P" & cl.Row).Value = .Range("P" & cl.Row).Value & IIf(Not .Range("P" & cl.Row).Value = vbNullString, ";", "") & Sheets("DRG").Range("S" & MatchRow + 1).Value ' "E" - Live ASIN ; "P" - Comments ; "S" - App Trail
        End If
    Next cl
End With
```

Comment: Do a search within SO using a search string of "excel-vba find column based on header" and you will find numerous examples of ways to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: I tried doing that..But I didnt know how to implement the same in the above code..So if i get to know how to do it in the above code for one instance, I can follow the same for rest of the places

Comment: show your efforts even if it's not quite working and we'll have a starting point to help you

Comment: I tried using the method : `LastRow = .Cells((.Rows.count, "Live ASIN",lookat:=xlWhole).EntireColumn).End(xlUp).Row )'"E" - Live ASIN` but it's showing syntax error.

Comment: you have to use `Find()` method like `lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.count,.Rows(1).Find(what:="Live ASIN",lookAt:=xlWhole, lookIn:=xlValues).Column).Row`

Comment: I'm getting a error message when i run the code after using the above code. Error in line  - `.Range("O" & cl.Row).Value = "Pass" '"O" - Pass/Fail`  - Compile error Statements and labels invalid